# Is there a way to specify filters using wildcards?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Our Visual studio project uses source-base with lot of directories and files.
Other programmers use other ides/systems and when they add new files in the source-base, visual-studio users have to re-add those files into corresponding filter directory (that is 1:1 following directory structure).

Isn't there way to say to visual studio, to follow the directory structure automatically? If that isn't possible, is it at least possible to specify filter contents by wildcards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a way to make it work in visual studio, but the workaround that solved it for us is the usage of fastbuild (http://fastbuild.org). Not only it can be used to speed up the compilation, but it can generate the visual studio files. This allows us to remove the visual studio files from the repository and just generate them on the fly. As the files are specified reasonably in fastbuild ([recursive] directories + file list + exluded files/directories), it automatically works when someone using linux just adds new cpp file into it.